# In Svelte JS, how does reactive variable work if some variable is just printed but doesn't participate in giving out a value?

Tags: svelte, reactive-variable

The code in https://svelte.dev/repl/f8db4771ba794c658d7c25a6e72d1b46?version=3.18.1

has two "reactive variables":

```
$: nameUpperCase = name.toUpperCase();

$: if (name === "city") { 
    console.log("RUNNING HERE 01", age);
} else {
    console.log("RUNNING HERE 02", age);
}
```

if the value of `name` changes, then `nameUpperCase` also get changed. This one is easy.

But for the second part, it seems when the value of `name` or `age` is changed, then the `if` line is evaluated.  If the `age` is removed from the `console.log()`, as in https://svelte.dev/repl/68c2cdea2bfd462caa5ac5519fb8b99d?version=3.18.1 then it doesn't matter if `age` changes. The `if` line is not evaluated.

But the `age` never participate in generating any final value for the `if` statement. It is merely printed out, and the `console.log` always return `undefined`.  So what is the rule?  Somehow Svelte "magically" gathers all variables after the `$:`, and then if any of them change, then execute the line after the `$:`?  So even if the variable doesn't participate in forming some final value, it still is considered?

Answer (score 19):

The way your question is framed, I think "yes" would be a proper answer.

It works exactly as you've described: **When any variable in the reactive block change, then the block gets executed.**

That's the rule. Simple. Predictable. See how you've intuited it all correctly by yourself?

It isn't anymore (or any less) magic than having the value of your variables automatically reflected in your view. Svelte already knows about all the (top level) variables in your code for that.

Whether the reative block "produces" a value or not (reactive *declaration* vs *statement*) is irrelevant. It's just "all the variables".

If you want to exclude a variable from being watched, then extract the processing that uses it from the reactive block:

```js
// runs when `name` or `age` change
$: if (name === "city") { 
    console.log("RUNNING HERE 01", age);
} else {
    console.log("RUNNING HERE 02", age);
}

const logAge = msg => console.log(msg, age)

// only runs when `name` changes
$: if (name === "city") { 
    logAge("RUNNING HERE 01");
} else {
    logAge("RUNNING HERE 02");
}
```

Comment: +1 : "If you want to exclude a variable from being watched, then extract the processing that uses it from the reactive block." This is important and I don't remember reading this in the docs.

Comment: A very big caveat to this is that if you change variable values in a function, then Svelte is prone to miss running the reactive block if the variable changes in a reactive block after it, making the order of reactive blocks matter.

I've created a REPL to demonstrate this.
https://svelte.dev/repl/fa9d518225a84f9a8099d196094e4ab3?version=3.53.1

Answer (score 5):

You're right. Svelte's reactivity is based on assignment.

The API says this:

> Any top-level statement (i.e. not inside a block or a function) can be made reactive by prefixing it with the $: . Reactive statements run immediately before the component updates, whenever the values that they depend on have changed.

Comment: For this line "Reactive statements run immediately before the component updates, whenever the values that they depend on have changed." but in this case, `age` is just printed, so no value really depends on `age`... but the reactive statement runs even though it doesn't depend on `age`. So I guess the rule is: if it "appears" that it depends on it... by "showing up" after the `$:`, then the line will run